# Xamarin "Sorry, this video cannot be played"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, media-player, android-videoview, setonerrorlistener

How can i handle this error?
please help me out of this situation.

```
private void previewVideo(){

            try{

            var path = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(App._file.AbsolutePath);

            preview.SetVideoURI (path);

            preview.Start ();

            }

            catch(Exception e){
                e.GetBaseException ();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your'e lucky that I was following your previous question. Please try to have your questions as detailed as possible so it's easier for us to analyze and possible replicate the error.

To be able to set an error listener on the VideoView, the VideoView needs an object that implements the `Android.Media.MediaPlayer.IOnErrorListener` interface.

You can accomblish that by letting your Activity implement the previous mentioned interface, and setting the Activity as the ErrorListener for the VideoView

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, Android.Media.MediaPlayer.IOnErrorListener
{
    
    ...

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        ...
        preview = FindViewById<VideoView> (Resource.Id.SampleVideoView);
        preview.SetOnErrorListener(this); // <- Set the error listener
        ...
    }

    ...

    //The implementation of MediaPlayer.IOnErrorListener
    public bool OnError(MediaPlayer player, MediaError error, int extra)
    {
        // Do Something here because error happened
    }

    ...
}
```

By doing this, when error occurs in the VideoView the VideoView will call the public `OnError` method.

From the [Android Docs of OnErrorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html) you can see what the `OnError` method should return.

> **Returns**:
>
> True if the method handled the error, false if it didn't. Returning false, or not having an OnErrorListener at all, will cause the OnCompletionListener to be called.